# How do I select data from the current row in sql and access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Think this may be an obvious question but have had a search and still cant seem to get this to work.

Basically I am trying to knock up a quick access database which will allow one field to limit what is shown in the next field.

So if the user selects a categories in one field it will then limit a subset of subcatories in the next field.

The way i have it set up for this part is I have a a mastertable which is what the user will use and then I have another table which contains each category and subcategory

ie.

```
category1 subcat1
category1 subcat2
category2 subcat1
etc.
```

How can I achieve this in access as I am unsure of how to select the current row data to use in the query.

This is what code i have but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT [Industry types].[Industry types] 
FROM [Industry types], MasterTable 
WHERE [Industry types].[Main Category] = [MasterTabel]![Industry Category 1];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: well I am stuck at the point of getting the table to display limited subcategories based on the category. this is the code I have currently but doesn't work SELECT [Industry types].[Industry types]
FROM [Industry types], MasterTable
WHERE  [Industry types].[Main Category] = [MasterTabel]![Industry Category 1];

Answer (score 0):

A query doesn't have an actual record.

You must display the information of the master table in a form and use a subform that will show the related records. The RecordSource of the main form must be the MasterTable or a query based on it. The subform's RecordSource must be [Industry types] table or a query based on it. You don't need a where clause, instead, you set the subform's `LinkChildFields` property to `Main Category` and `LinkMasterFileds` property to `Industry Category 1`.

See [Create a form that contains a subform (a one-to-many form)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx)